# Xcode 7.2 leap day code signing failure?? Anyone else?

Tags: ios, xcode

While building the same project on the same devices that were working yesterday, today (which is 02/29, leap day), I am getting a code signing error that I do not recall having seen before today.

[image]*.*

Comment: Have you edited your certificate for, example, adding or removing a device on Apple Developer?

Comment: No change since yesterday. Literally built, ran, tested, checked in, closed the laptop - all was well with the world - opened the laptop today and this. I set the date on both iOS devices and the laptop back to the 28th, no change. I created a new project and it is giving the same errors. Fun stuff...

Comment: what about your certificate, maybe it is really expired?

Comment: it's relate to your provision profile and certificate!

Comment: My iOS development cert appears to be good until 2017, still no dice.

Comment: And you are certain your system date and time are set correctly?

Comment: FWIW, I have gotten my share of inexplicable code signing errors that had nothing to do with leap days, but still sorted themselves out after a few reboots or a day's steaming. Maybe there's a certificate and profile mismatch, or maybe Xcode's just being thick about. If nothing else helps, you can try removing the certificates from keychain and re-adding them, or even completely re-creating them with a new certificate request.

Comment: Sorry, write this off as inexplicable. Resetting my profile and rebooting one time did not fix it. Doing so three times did. I think perhaps burning some sage and waving a rubber chicken over the computer while wearing a funny hat and chanting might have helped. :-/